# ActionCable not executing subscribed in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I'm playing with ActionCable, the very basic setup.

I've this on client side:

```
App.chat = App.cable.subscriptions.create "ChatChannel",
  subscribed: ->
    console.log 'subscribed'
  test: ->
    @perform("test")
```

On server

```
class ChatChannel < AC..::Channel
  def subscribed
    Rails.logger.info "This is never printed in the logs"
  end
  def test
    Rails.logger.info "This is never printed in the logs"
  end
end
```

On the JS console I can see:

```
[ActionCable] Opening WebSocket, current state is null, subprotocols: actioncable-v1-json,actioncable-unsupported 1494360634092
[ActionCable] ConnectionMonitor started. pollInterval = 3000 ms 1494360634096
[ActionCable] WebSocket onopen event, using 'actioncable-v1-json' subprotocol 1494360634733
[ActionCable] ConnectionMonitor recorded connect 1494360634734
```

On the server log I see:

```
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-09 15:10:34 -0500
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 09/05/2017 03:10 PM
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Registered connection (Z2lkOi8vcHJvcGhvL1VzZXIvMg)
```

If I send a broadcast message from server it's never received on the client. If I try to perform an action from the client it returns false and nothing appear on the console.

The network tab shows:

```
Request URL:ws://0.0.0.0:3000/cable
Request Method:GET
Status Code:101 Switching Protocols (with a green status icon)
```

I'm not using redis, starting server with `rails server`

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
```

Comment: Just figured that i'm including `pace.js` a javascript loading animation script. Seems like that is causing the problem

Comment: If you are using Pace.js a warkaround is setting the `trackWebSockets` option to `false`, more information here: https://github.com/HubSpot/pace/issues/411

Answer (score 0):

try it.

```
App.chat = App.cable.subscriptions.create "ChatChannel",
  # subscribed: ->
  #   console.log 'subscribed'
  # test: ->
  #   @perform("test")

  connected: ->
    @perform("test")
```